# What is degree of a polynomial f(n) = n/20

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures, polynomial-math

If an algorithm executes a statement,  it is n/2 times, then how come O is equal to O(n). Because the video explains that it is because of the degree of a polynomial. Please explain.

```
for(int i =0;i<n;i=i+2){
sout(n) ---- This statemet can be print n/2 times
}

f(n) = n/2  then O(n)
```

Comment: Big O notation is the order in which runtime (typically) is expected to grow in relation to input size. Constants are discarded because it is the order of growth (or degree) that is being discussed.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, although the statement will be printed `n/2` times, it still holds a linear relationship with `n`.

For n=10, it will print 5 times.

For n=50, it will print 25 times.

For n=100, it will print 50 times.

Notice the linear relationship. The factor `1/2` is just multiplied by `n`. It is a linear relationship and `O(n)` signifies a linear relation and doesn't care of the constant (which is `1/2` in this case). Even `f(n) = n/3` would have been `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Aoerz already said, to understand your problem, you should understand what the O notation means.

In a math way:

```
O(f(n)) = {g(n) : ∃c>0 ∧ n0 ≥ 0 | g(n) ≤ c*f(n) ∀ n ≥ n0}
```

so `g(n) ∈ O(f(n)) if g(n) ≤ c*f(n)` (after a certain `n0` and a constant `c`)

To put it in a easy way, think of `n` as a really big number. How much all the other factors matter? So what's the only main factor that really matter?

Example:
`f(n) = n^3 + 300*n +5 --> f(n) ∈ O(n^3)` (try it with `n=100` and you'll see that is already enough)